# WebSocketException (0x80004005): The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, websocket

I have a Xamarin app that communicates using WebSocket. On the client side, I am referencing the **`ClientWebSocket`**.

code:

```
using (var client = new ClientWebSocket() { Options = { KeepAliveInterval = new TimeSpan(0,0,3,0) }})
{
    try
    {
        await client.ConnectAsync(requestUri, cancellationToken);
        do
        {
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = null;
            var buffer = new byte[ReceiveChunkSize];
            var message = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer);
            do
            {
                result = await client.ReceiveAsync(message, cancellationToken);
                var receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);
                data.Append(receivedMessage);
                if (result.MessageType != WebSocketMessageType.Text)
                    break;

            } while (!result.EndOfMessage);

            TranslateData(data);
        } while (client.State == WebSocketState.Open && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested);
```

The application keeps throwing intermittently:

```
 System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The remote
 party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close
 handshake.
```

The server has a test website where it seems to function as expected. It seems the problem is on the client. The value in the `client.State` is `Open`.

Comment: Client gone offline without close handshake. The usual case. Just handle exseptions of this type to prevent any harm to your system.

Comment: The issue is  probably at server-side, it doesn't close WebSocket connection properly.

Comment: Any guesses what could be going wrong on the server in terms of process for closing the connection

Comment: @ArshadBadarKhan the code can be written wrong: the server simply ignores closing. If, for example, the server is .Net on Windows, the code closes http context without calling `await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Closing", CancellationToken.None);` first.

Comment: See [RFC, closing handshake section](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#page-9). High chances that server just closes the connection.

Answer (score 2):

**If anybody still findes the question like me...**

I had the same problem and I added this check

```
result = await client.ReceiveAsync(message, cancellationToken);

if (result.Count == 0) {
    break;
}
```

Getting zero bytes somehow also means that the server ended the connection or something went wrong...

And I added a timer around the WebSocket to do a ping -> pong type check of the connection. Of course this is only possible if you also control the server side code. On the server side this helps you, to detect dead connections.

Links that helped me were:

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/77bda5ed-0d52-4305-9a20-438e69dc2cb0/c-advanced-socket-server-100-cpu-usage-after-some-time?forum=csharpgeneral

And - like aleha_84 wrote. An exception in your loop should also trigger a reconnect.